# Online service for storing key/value pairs?

Tags: java, android, key-value

I am developing an android application. It does http communication with a web server. As of now, the web server IP address is hard coded. In the future, if I change to a different server with some other IP address, then I have to change the code. I know that probably having domain name/static address will solve this issue. But since my native app is specific for small devices, I need to find alternative easy solution.

As a solution, I am thinking of storing the key/value pairs in an online store service. So the app can query the online service for server ip and use the configured value. If IP changes, then I need to do modification in online service and need not change the app code. Is there any service which suits to my purpose?

Also are there any other better solutions to my requirement?

Comment: `But since my app is specific for small devices` that prevents you from having a domain name, how?

Comment: actually doesn't prevent it... but I think it is unnecessary since it is native app...

Comment: what about push notification.

Comment: so, you have a server, it has an ip, which may change, but your solution to that is to ask the ip to a third party server that would hold it for you. That's called DNS, and that's what having a domain name is about.

Comment: check https://parse.com/ it may be helpful

Comment: @nafas As I understand push notification is for the user of an app and may not be for the app itself. But not sure... will appreciate some more details regarding this...

Comment: @Omkar, as I far as I know, you can use it to broadcast a message, this message can then be used to update some info on your application (e.g. if you store your ip in sqllight, u can update it)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [keyvalue.xyz](http://keyvalue.xyz). It is cloud key/value store service with REST API.

*Disclaimer: I have developed the system.*

Comment: Nice job on this tool, very easy to use!

Comment: API seems to be down (I get `Could not resolve host: api.keyvalue.xyz`)

Comment: Same here. I think they are down. Could not resolve host: api.keyvalue.xyz

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in [kvdb.io](https://kvdb.io). It's a key-value store like DynamoDB or Redis, but with a much simpler REST API that you can use from Curl, jQuery or anywhere you can make an HTTP request.

*Disclaimer: I built the service.*

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements really sound like dynamic dns, but to be specific on the key/value store, what about having some object storage on [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)?

Overkill? Or maybe you don't want to spend money?

The good thing is that you would get a REST interface to your objects, so it works quite easily from an application point of view ([Amazon SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/)).

Comment: Amazon elastic beanstalk solved my problem. Earlier I was connecting to vm instance of Google cloud platform with corresponding ip address. With beanstalk, it provides url with default domain and specific application name. Eg., http://appname-env.elasticbeanstalk.com. So no need to buy a new domain for my native app.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to look at a dynamic DNS hosting service. The service would handle the DNS updates if your IP address should ever change. Read up on 
[DNS on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) or this great [explanation on godaddy.com](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422)

Comment: meeiot.org has key=value queue=values and custom headers on get/pop. Also requires a user token which looks more long and more secure